# Specifying field in attribute table with raster calculator using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

How can I specify the attribute field to use in the raster calculator of ArcMap 10.2?

In 9.x, I used the dot notation.

i.e. To use the "New_Value" field, I could do the following:

```
[MyRaster].New_Value + 1 = new raster
```

This doesn't appear to work in 10.2?

Answer (score 11):

While researching to write an [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101584/cause-of-arcgis-raster-calculator-parsing-error-type-exceptions-syntaxerror/101626#101626) to [Cause of ArcGIS Raster Calculator Parsing error <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101584), I found [Raster Calculator trouble](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-spatial-analyst-questions/raster-calculator-trouble/m-p/605767#M8810) that states dot notation doesn't work in Raster Calculator beginning with 10.0. The forum post suggests using [Lookup](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sn000000) to create a separate raster from the second field. It also suggests this can be accomplished *in* the Raster Calculator by using:

```
Lookup("rastername","fieldname")
```

Comment: I can confirm, this works in raster calculator.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a choice, don't use raster fields -- run length encoding means that the less spatially complex your data are, the more efficient your raster storage *and* processing will be. Grids with many attributes are generally going to be more spatially complex, and the Lookup() tool can be costly too. So unless your data really demand it, I recommend avoiding raster tables / lookups / etc. Store your data in the raster value.