# Specify field of raster in Raster Calculator expression of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

In Raster Calculator I need to apply the next expression:

```
Con("raster1%","field3")==Integer, Lookup("%raster2%","field3"),Lookup("raster1%","field3"))
```

or more specifically:

```
Con("%alteracionMapeada_raster%"==8,Lookup("%swir%","CLASS_NAME"),Lookup("%alteracionMapeada_raster%","OCURREN16"))
```

The `"%raster2%"`,`"field3"` and `"raster1%"`,`"field3"` are categorical values so I need to get those values (form `"%raster2%"`,`"field3"` and `"raster1%"`,`"field3"`) in the output raster cells. The problem is that the results is just one numerical field (no other fields with categorical).

I have already checked [Specify a field in attribute table with raster calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102503/specify-a-field-in-attribute-table-with-raster-calculator) and the answer about the lookup tool has very promising but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "field3" columns are string/text format...

Your `Lookup` is working, but the text values are getting dropped in the `Con` output.

Another way to get your desired result is to use the [Combine](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/combine.htm) tool then Add Join and Calculate Field tools.

Below is the sequence (as python just to demonstrate, you'll probably need to run the tools manually to make sure all the parameters, especially the field calculator expression, are correct):

```py
r3 = arcpy.sa.Combine("r1;r2")
r3.save("r3")

arcpy.management.AddField("r3", "Field3", "TEXT", None, None, None, None, "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", None)    
arcpy.management.AddJoin("r3", "r1", "r1", "Value", "KEEP_ALL")
arcpy.management.AddJoin("r3", "r2", "r2", "Value", "KEEP_ALL")    
arcpy.management.CalculateField("r3", "VAT_r3.Field3", "!VAT_r1.Field3! if !VAT_r1.Value! == 8 else !VAT_r2.Field3!", "PYTHON3", None)

arcpy.management.RemoveJoin("r3", "VAT_r1")
arcpy.management.RemoveJoin("r3", "VAT_r2")
```

[image]