# Specify attribute from raster's attribute table for raster calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, raster-calculator

I'm working with the ModelBuilder in ArcMap version 10.5.
I have two layers : one is a raster that has only 1 value per pixel. The second layer is a raster that has  4 attributes.
I want to use the raster calculator in order to subtract the second layer from the first layer.
The problem is that I don't find any way to specify the attribute that I want to use for the subtraction.

I have seen [Specify a field in attribute table with raster calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102503) and tried using lookup :

```
Lookup("layer_1","attribute")-"layer2"
```

Also tried to write it like this:

```
"layer_1"."attribute"-"layer2
```

But that didn't work and I get errors.
I have also tried to drop the other fields but it did not allow to drop any of the other attributes, and the only one I could subtract was the one I need.

**Is there any way I can select the correct attribute for my calculation?**

Comment: You need to create a separate raster from a second.  Use Lookup tool for that

Comment: Wow! This Lookup("layer_1","attribute") does work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much faster way to create raster in memory through Image Analysis window, e.g. in no time you  can go from integer raster to float:

[image]

[image]

/Don't forget to specify output type on Genaral tab./

[image]